# NodeJS; Gulp download files from SFTP

Tags: node.js, gulp, sftp

I was wondering if i can download files into my project with gulp. I've seen the gulp-sftp package which seems only to work to upload files,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the npm package remote-sync works great in combination with gulp. It is running with lftp which has the option to mirror an sftp folder. On the [npm download page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-sync) are a lot of examples how to use it!

I'm using the commands / operations:

*to upload*

```
mirror --overwrite --delete --only-newer -R ./source-folder /target-folder
```

*to download*

```
mirror --overwrite --delete --only-newer /target-folder ./source-folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [gulp-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-download).  Here is some sample code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const download = require("gulp-download");
const decompress = require('gulp-decompress');

const url = 'https://potoococha.net/feather.zip';

gulp.task('unzip', function () {

  download(url)

    .pipe(decompress())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("unzipped"));
});
```

Comment: I'm actually checking out the [remote-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-sync) npm which seems to work the way I need it, but i have to figure it out first, im new to the nodejs stuff :D

Comment: ... because your option doesn't seem to include sftp download, only http(s).